# Problem with declaration of variables in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have declared 2 PowerShell variables

```
$prm=Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Computer . -Filter "vendor = 'Wolters Kluwer Financial Services'" | Select-Object Name, Vendor, Version
$rgteng=Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Computer . -Filter "vendor = 'WKFS'" | Select-Object Name, Vendor, Version
```

I want the output of this variable to a text file o/p `@{Name=Wolters Kluwer Financial Services Regulatory Reporting FRA Param 11.2.0; Vendor=Wolters Kluwer Financial Services; Version=11.2.0}`, I want this o/p to a text file.

I have tried using `Write-Output` and `Write-Host`, but none of them gives right o/p

Comment: what do you mean by `but none of them gives right o/p`? what is the _expected_ output and what is different from your _actual_ output?

Comment: when i Use Write-host it display in the screen , i am noobie to powershell , when I use Write Output with this variable , it is displaying the o/p in text file , when i put in powershell script it is not executed, somehow , does  Out-File override the existing contents ,let me know thanks

Comment: ah! that is a standard object with 3 properties. it doesn't normally go to a _text_ file ... one normally uses `Export-CSV` to send such to a CSV file. ///// using `$VariableName | Out-String | Set-Content $FileName` will give you the same text as what you see on the screen display.

Answer (score 0):

What happens there looks like this (just the big picture):

1. `Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Computer . -Filter "vendor = 'Wolters Kluwer Financial Services'"` creates an WMI object and pipes it to the next command
2. `Select-Object Name, Vendor, Version` transforms that object into a new PSCustom type object (more like a table version of your WMI object wtih only the desired information)

Then it gets messy :

- if you use write-host or display it on the screen , the output will be formatted according the the powershell's settings (those settings can be changed by altering xml files)
- if you use `export-csv` you basically use a `convertto-csv | out-file  c:\sometheing.txt` + **some formatting rules that are applied**. (I think the UTF-8 type of the file is changed but I am not sure...)

So if you want to know exactly how your variable / file will look like, without having powershell formatting interfering with your work,  use `convertto-csv | out-file`.